# How would I write this method in java?

Tags: java, python

I just wrote this method in python, a very simple one. but I'm having trouble pulling it off in Java.

```
def space():
    space = "_"
    for x in range(5):
        print(x * space)
```

the output for the Python program is:

```
_
__
___
____
```

ultimately I'm trying to fix my java program which is not working the way I want it to.

This is a piece of a java program that prints the pascal triangle right side up and up side down.

```
for(int outer = 0; outer < lines; outer++)
        {
            for(int count = 0; count < index; count++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for(int inner = 0; inner < outer; inner++)
            {
                System.out.print(myTriangle.Triangle(outer, inner) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            index--;
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        for(int outer = lines; outer > 0; outer--)//revers
        {
            for(int count = 0; count < index; count++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for(int inner = 0; inner < outer; inner++)
            {
                System.out.print(myTriangle.Triangle(outer, inner) + " ");//maybe something should be done here
            }
            System.out.println();
            index--;
        }
    }
```

The output for this program is:

```
   1 
  1 1 
 1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
1 2 1 
1 1 
1
```

I want the output to look like this

```
   1 
  1 1 
 1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
 1 2 1 
  1 1 
   1
```

Comment: I don't see the connection between the first part in Python and what you're trying to do... So, what _are_ you trying to do? Please read [ask].

Comment: I am trying to add spaces on the java program when the triangle starts to print up side down the out up should look like a "diamond shape"

Comment: What's the connection with the Python script?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would help, my apologies. I needed to add spaces to the java output exactly how I did in my python script. I was thinking if I could figure out how to do what I did in python, then I could implement the learning in the java program.

Answer (score 1):

Change this `index--;` to `index++;` in `//revers`. You went to `0` with it in first `for`, so this:

```
 for(int count = 0; count < index; count++)
                System.out.print(" ");
```

will never execute since you go to minus with `index`.

Comment: do you mean the count++? I do not see an index-- in the program

Comment: then whats that in last line of each second level for?